# Unable to extract the text using gettext in Selenium WebDriver and also unable to click it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to find the `gettext` of the below code in the Selenium WebDriver.

```
<a id="551" class="blueTextNormal1 spc" onclick="sPh(this,'079');return false;" title="079">Country</a>
```

I want to get the value of Country. I tried using the `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']").getText())
```

but it is not returning any value. When I tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']")).getAttribute("title"))
```

I am getting the value as "079".

How can I to proceed?

Comment: It's working for me:  driver.find_element(:id, "551").text

Comment: It's also working for me using xpath: driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@id='551']").text

Comment: @TDHM The one which you specified will not work for Java as well as OP.

Comment: Plenty of answers here, but no discussion of which approach is better than the other. Refer the differences between "innerText", "textContent" etc. from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose and also https://medium.com/better-programming/whats-best-innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-textcontent-903ebc43a3fc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 31):

It depends on the code as well. Give a try with the below code:

Instead of `getText()`, please use `getAttribute("innerHTML")` which will then return what you are looking for, including any HTML that is invisible.

```
<div class="no-docs-selected">
    <p class="icon-alert">Please select a doc</p>
</div>
```

I was looking for `Please select a doc`, but I didn't succeed with `getText()`. But the below one worked.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='icon-alert']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: hi @joe 
I am new to selenium, whatever you have suggested has worked for me but i don't have any clarification and i.e. when to go for getAttribute("atrb") and when to go for getText()? I tried to search for the reason but couldn't find any concrete results.

Answer (score 18):

I faced the same issue, and then I updated .getText() to **.getAttribute("textContent")** and it worked.

Comment: Where does the attribute name *"textContent"* come from? Is it literal?

Comment: That shall be an attribute in the HTML for the field.

Comment: [for python devs] I just tried `.get_attribute("textContent")`, and it is working fine for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is really surprising you are able to get attribute title, but not text.

Try with

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//a[@id='551' and contains(text(),'Country')]")).isDisplayed();
```

or

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//a[@id='551' and text()='Country']")).isDisplayed();
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for Replying [link](driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='551' and contains(text(),'Country')]")).isDisplayed());) iam getting False I Think because of onclick="sPh(this,'079') we are getting as "false" and if iam trying driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='551']")).click()   getting error. org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration

Comment: Hi Everyone, this is the website http://www.redbus.in/ here i want to take the phone numbers of each city. The phone numbers will come after  when we click on each city . eg. Ahmedabad,Bangalore etc.. Hopes so this helps to understand the application.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a case where `getAttribute("innerHTML")` worked, but not `getText()`. It turned out that the element was present, but it was not visible or displayed.

When I scrolled to the element first before calling `getText()` it worked.

```
    if(!element.isDisplayed()) 
        scrollIntoView(element);
    element.getText();
```

The `scrollIntoView` function is like this:

```
    public void scrollIntoView(WebElement element) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
```

I therefore don't need to use getAttribute("innerHTML")`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```java
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("error")).getAttribute("textContent"));
```

Code:

```
driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Hello");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Hello");
driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("error")).getAttribute("textContent"));
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a typo while copying to Stack Overflow, you are missing a parentheses before getText. Change
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']").getText())` to  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']")).getText()`

I tried the following code, and it worked perfectly for me.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("C:\\test.html");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='551']")).getAttribute("title"));
```

Comment: Thanks @buddha, i have tested,  only the getattribute is returning the value as 079 but not the getText(); i have tested  using By.xpath("//a[@id='551' and text()='Country']")).isDisplayed();it is returning false

Comment: Finally i was able to solve the issue the element was hidden so i used the `WebElement labelNode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='551']"));
      String labelNodeText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML",labelNode); `  was able to return the required ahmedabad. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<WebElement>.getAttribute("value")` to extract the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text1 = driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value='EFASTGTC']/../ancestor::tr[1]/scipt[1]").getAttribute("innerText"); 
        
System.out.println("Value=" + text1);
```

This code will work if you want text written between script tag.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I used `getAttribute("innerText")` instead of `getText()`.

```java
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("modalError")).getAttribute("innerText"));
```

Comment: please format the code snippet (as .. well .. code :) to make it readable

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, this worked for me:

```
.getAttribute("innerHTML");
.getAttribute("innerText");
.getAttribute("outerText");
```

Comment: This is hardly an answer. On what do you call these methods? A WebElement? If so, how do you find that? Also note that an attribute is different from an element's text content.